# How to solve $tx'' -3x'+x=0$, x(0) = 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to solve this problem using Laplace transforms when only one initial condition is given?  I've gotten to a point in the problem where I have

$$-s^2X'(s) +(1-5s)X(s) = x''(0)$$

Is there a way to solve for $x(t)$ from here?

Comment: Are you asked to solve the diff. eq. using Laplace transform method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you get the $x''(0)$.  The Laplace transform of your differential equation should be
$$ -s^2 X'(s) + (1-5 s) X(s) + 4 x(0)   = 0$$   After plugging in $x(0)=0$, you have a 
first-order differential equation to solve.  Of course the solution will have a free parameter, because your single initial condition is not enough to determine a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear first order equation of the form
$$y' + p(x)y = q(x).$$
Multiply both sides by $\mu(x) = \exp\{\int p(x)\, dx\}$.
Undo the product rule on the left hand side and integrate.